# Migrate GIT commits to existing TFS

Tags: git, tfs, migration

I have the following scenario:

- The client is using the TFS Source control. A repository is already in place there, containing a version A of the application
- A GIT repository was created for the TFS repository. This wasn't made using git-tf or any other application, a folder from TFS was copied in the GIT folder manually
- Work was done on GIT repository, and now it contains version B of the application

What we want to achieve now, is move all the commits that were made on GIT into the TFS, so that the TFS will contain the version B of the application and to have one (or more) checkins on TFS to see the changes from version A to version B.

What I was able to find so far was that git-tf can be used to achieve this if the GIT repository is made using git-tf from the TFS source. Since this was not the case for us, is there another way to automatically retrieve the files that were modified on GIT and check them in on the TFS?

Thank you,

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a git repo?

Comment: @Someone TFS also support Git, If you mean that you vesrsion control in local Git or other third Git, and want to migrate to TFS Git, then you just need to remove current origin and Add the TFS as the origin, then push the changes to TFS. (`git remote -v
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin http://server：8080/tfs/collectionlc/_git/xxx`). If you want to use TFVC, then follow MrKekson's answer below.

Comment: @Someone Have you resolved the issue by below answers, any udpate?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for not replying for so long, with the holidays and all it was a hectic period. We messed it up with the git-tfs because the git was created manually from sources and was missing parts and we ended up creating a script to get from git the commits and files and copy them to the tfs sources and checkin there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), to migrate our repo. It can handle branches, and even 2 way sync if needed. The documentation is a bit fuzzy sometimes(sources are available tho :P). But you can sync a tfs and a git repo with it. I think it can squash your git commits into one tfs check-in, but worst case every git commit will be a tfs chk-in.

Good luck tho :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes git-tfs could help you:

1. 'git tfs quick-clone' giving the last common commit
2. Then add a remote toward your current git repository and fetch
   2bis. Eventually, squash all your commits
3. Use 'git rebase --onto' to replay all the commits onto the commit you fetch from TFVC (I hope you don't have branches)
4. Use 'git tfs rcheckin' to push the history to tfvc